# How do I make a turtle invisible without disabling it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a simple exit button, which hides itself along with the text just like a popup window. I am required to use the turtle module in python.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.screensize(1280, 720)

# instructional text

#create text
texty = turtle.Turtle()
texty.penup()
texty.setpos(60,-360)
texty.write("Instructions have been hidden from Stack Overflow for privacy reasons: \nUse WASD to Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla. \nHold the space bar to bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.", move=False, align='left', font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))

# create exit symbol
texty.setpos(580,-290)
texty.shape("circle")
texty.color("red")
texty.pensize(32)
texty.stamp()
texty.color("black")
texty.right(90)
texty.forward(16)
texty.write("X", move=False, align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))
texty.backward(16)
texty.hideturtle() #disables the turtle when I don't want it to. I just want the turtle to be invisible.

def hideText(x,y):
    texty.clear()

texty.onclick(hideText)

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I tried to draw out the 'X' using turtle, but the hit box for the exit button was the last circle drawn, which is way too small.

Comment: what makes you think `texty.hideturtle()` disables. it. You can move this line to be just after you define `texty` and it will still draw everything so clearly its not disabling it.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I have the texty.hideturtle() at its current position for troubleshooting purposes. When I click on the exit button in the Python Turtle Graphics program, it does not do anything. The exit button is supposed to hide the text and itself when it's clicked on.

Comment: that because the exit button isnt a button, its just a drawing. you need to click on turtle to trigger the on click, and you have hidden it so not sure how this is meant to work

Comment: @ChrisDoyle When the turtle is visible, it is a black circle, which is shown layered on top of the exit button. I want either the turtle to function as an invisible hit box or the drawing to trigger the clear turtle event.